# Why changes a new branch in detached head state all the parent refs?

Tags: git, git-log, git-detached-head

If I compare the [git/refs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) when creating a new branch from last commit of a branch versus creating from a detached head state, the git/refs shows different behavior (names) and I like to understand why.

Lets assume the head is on master.

[image]

I need a new dev branch. After that, I made some commits to the new branch and some fixes on master.

[image]

Now I see another way how to solve the dev branch and I made a second new branch and some commits on that and on master again some fixes.

[image]

But now the refs look different! As long as I don't merge plus delete or only delete the second branch still the first two refs called after that second branch.

Why is this a good behavior, cause I cannot easily see that the first refs usually belong to master? Only hashes and parent hashes help with identification, but are a slow method. THX.

EDIT: The information shown here is provided from `git log` command.

Comment: So, the issue you are experience is not a Git problem, but rather how you interpret the information given by some tool (`git log` I suspect?).

Comment: Your are right, the information is presented by `git log` but isn't it delivered by git, right?

Comment: what options do you pass to `git log` ?

Comment: `git` does not store the information "this commit was first committed on branch xyz". If you ask for something like "name a ref that contains this commit", git may return any such ref

Comment: The relevant options here are `--all --graph` and in `--pretty=format:` we have the commit placeholders p, h, D, S and s.

Comment: "`git` does not store the information "this commit was first committed on branch xyz"": I see this a little different, but may be wrong. Under `.git/logs/refs/heads/` for every branch the commits are logged with timestamps. In my example you can clearly say where it happens first.

Comment: Both logs-files of the two branches show that they derive from `052b272`. But strangely only the second one has an impact how `git log` show me the refs for the first two commits. That's what I need to understand ;) and as @0andriy mentioned may only be a problem of `git log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other version control systems you may be familiar with, commits don't belong to any branch. Instead, a branch is just a label that points to a commit. There's no definitive answer to the question "which branch does a commit belong to" or "which branch was a commit written on". Instead, you can only say what commits are reachable by a branch. And that's just what `%S` does. It works just like `--source`.

```
   --source
       Print out the ref name given on the command line by which each commit was
       reached.
```

In your instance, the first two commits 052b272 and adbf0ae can be reached by several branches. In your first example, by master. In your second by master and B-1. And in your third, by master, B-1, and B-2.

`git log --all` works by walking the commit graph starting from each reference. If it can reach a commit by multiple refs, it picks whichever ref it happened to be starting from when it prints the log line. Your second log could have easily said they came from B-1 or master. If you make another commit, it may change.

If you run `git log` without `--all`, it will say `HEAD` for all the commits because without `--all` it works backwards only from `HEAD`, the current commit.

Comment: "git log --all works by walking the commit graph starting from each reference..." This is the most interesting part of your answer for me. Exactly this selection process I like to understand. Okay, maybe you have said it all, but only deleting the branch B-2 leads to another pick or another new branch from detached head state.

Comment: Now I understand that a branch points to a commit and from that I can go backward (maybe more important than the interesting part above ;)) and therefore any ref is a valid result (credits also go to @LeGEC).

Comment: @onemorequestion I'm not 100% sure, but I assume `git log` acts [deterministically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm). Given the same history it will produce the same result. It's not picking a branch at random each time. Adding a commit or deleting a branch would can the result. One could dig into `git-log` and figure out exactly what their algorithm is, but there's no guarantee it won't change in the next version.